# Unity3D pong, improve choice of where ball hits

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm totally new to coding and I'm trying to create a ping pong game.

I scripted that the enemy paddle position to move with the ball position. (very simple)

```
public float speed = 6f;
Vector2 player2;
Vector2 player2position;
GameObject ballpos; 

void Start () 
{
   ballpos = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ball");
}

void Update()
{
player2 = Vector2.Lerp (gameObject.transform.position , ballpos.transform.position , Time.deltaTime * speed );
player2position = new Vector2 ( 3.1f , Mathf.Clamp ( player2.y , -2.4f, 2.4f)) ;
gameObject.transform.position = new Vector2 ( 3.1f , player2position.y ); 
}
```

What is code do is that the ""center"" of the enemy paddle will move with respect to the ""center"" of the ball.

Now what I'm trying to do is to let the enemy hit the ball randomly to different directions, so that collision between the enemy paddle and the ball happened on the edges of the enemy paddle. (not always with the center).

Also, I have set a distance between the ball and the enemy paddle, so that when if the distance > 3 the enemy paddle will stop.

```
if (Mathf.Abs (ballpos.transform.position.x - paddle.transform.position.x) > 3)
{
    speed = 0f;
}

if (Mathf.Abs (ballpos.transform.position.x - paddle.transform.position.x) < 3)
{
    speed = 6f;  
}
```

can you please help me with this. I have been trying to do this about two days.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add Physics Material component to your ball for bounciness effect, and to move both players use simple movement script.
Now to know ball position you can use OnCollisionEnter2D function and another function that calculates the ball's speed depending on where it hit.

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {


        if (col.gameObject.name == "PlayerLeft") // collide with left player
{

            float y = AFactor(transform.position,
                                col.transform.position,
                                col.collider.bounds.size.y);

            // Calculate direction, make length=1 via .normalized
            Vector2 dir = new Vector2(1, y).normalized;

            // Set Velocity with dir * speed
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = dir * speed;
        }


        if (col.gameObject.name == "PlayerRight")// hit right player
 {

            float y = AFactor(transform.position,
                                col.transform.position,
                                col.collider.bounds.size.y);

            // Calculate direction, make length=1 via .normalized
            Vector2 dir = new Vector2(-1, y).normalized;

            // Set Velocity with dir * speed
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = dir * speed;
        }
```